# how to fix Heating issue of 7805?

Tags: power-supply, dc, 7805

i am using LM7805 whose output voltage 5V and Output Current 1A 
i have used this to feed 5V supply for my application Circuit and 
my application circuit draw 125mA current ,
even tho 125mA current is less than the 1000 mA my LM7805 is slightly 
heated and application circuit not behave like its original functionality
so what should be the probable issue that my power supply circuit is having do you think and please let me know 
and sorry for my poor english !!!
thank you !!!

[image]

---

Problem got solved and  this  issue is because of microcontroller oscillator frequency and after scaling down this frequency problem got solved !!!

Comment: if the 7805 is only 'slightly heated', it's unlikely to be malfunctioning due to heating. (12v-5v)*125mA is about 1 watt, so I'd expect 'slight heating'. You have capacitors before and after the 7805, which is good, forgetting the output capacitor is a frequent cause of problems. Can you measure the output voltage? Does your application work with an alternative 5v supply?

Comment: I getting 5 volt at the output of LM7805 right now i don't have external 5 Volt power supply to test this

Comment: sounds good. Does the app work with a different source of 5v?

Comment: Does your application work with an alternative 5v supply? – No 
 i dont have external supply !!

Comment: Actually i dont have right capacitor value  so i have used near by capacitor value in my power supply unit

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem in this LM7805 power source? The problem could be in the "application circuit".

Comment: Actual Cin = 0.33uF and Cout = 0.1uF instead of this i have used 2.2uF so whatever the problem i am facing is due this fluctuation  ????

Comment: Ya Chupacabras your assumption also right i will check for this !!!!

Comment: bigger input and output caps? Should be no problem. How are you going to verify that your application works then?

Comment: i think it may be firmware issue i have upload  hex file of different application  into my application hardware and application  is working fine but for particular hex file its give me garbage output

Answer (score 9):

Making heat is *how the 7805 works*.

It is a dissipative voltage regulator.   That means it sits in series with the load, and is more or less a variable resistor, making resistive heat so as to make the output voltage 5v.

If you input 12V, it causes a 7 volt voltage drop by making heat.

In your case that would be 7 volts x 125ma or 875mw, plus its own internal usage/heat    Almost a watt of heat!  More than your load is using.   If you are on batteries it is wasting 7/12 of your battery capacity.

However it is simple and cheap.  That's what makes 7805s special.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I'd call it *resistive*, though if I squint I could see where you're coming from. Certainly 'dissipative'. While a 7805 has resistors in it, all the power stuff is done by a transistor, not a resistor. Even 'behaves as a series resistor' doesn't really quite cut it, in my book. 'Makes heat, the same way a resistor would', yes, I'd go for that.

Comment: +1 "More than your load is using" Always does as long as the input voltage >2x the output voltage.

Comment: +1 not much different, but add 60mW on top for the regulator itself (12V x 5mA typical) and you get 935mW, which will probably be too hot to hold your finger on for long (assuming no heatsink).

Answer (score 2):

Harper already explained the theory behind it. Here is some additional info and stuff that you can do to improve the circuit:

As per datasheet:

[image: Facts]

1 A output current is possible only if you take away the generated heat. To achieve this, you can attach a heat sink to your 7805 IC. It looks something like this:

[image: heat sink]

This should improve your circuit. If it's still heating up, you can probably use a bigger heat sink:

[image: bigger heat sink]

However, you will still be wasting a decent amount of power. If you want to save that, you can go for a switching regulator rather than a linear one. The circuit is not as straightforward as 7805, though:

[image: sw reg]

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an LM7805, and a 12V supply, and I assume you don't want to replace everything, I'll try to show you a fix with minimal changes.

First understand that anything passing a current, with a voltage difference between its terminals, is dissipating power, and getting hot, so you must find out how much power that 7805 is dissipating as heat:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTAUub.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Currents in and out of the regulator are roughly equal, about 125mA, and the voltage across the regulator is 7V. That means power dissipated is:

$$ P = I \times V = 125mA \times 7V = 0.88W $$

That's enough power to make it get hot enough that it becomes painful to touch. Depending on how you mount the 7805, and air flow around it, it might even get hot enough to invoke its own internal over-temperature shutdown.

The solution could be as simple as mounting a heat-sink onto it, as suggested by @WhiskeyJack.

There's a cheap "hack", to share this wasted power between the regulator and a resistor, so that the regulator is relieved of much of the burden of reducing 12V down to 5V, staying much cooler. Simply add a resistor, R1 shown here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1a7Ai.png)</sup>

At a maximum load of 125mA, both resistor R1 and the regulator share some of the 12V-5V difference, about 3.5V each.

Power dissipated in the resistor is:

$$ P_{R1} = 125mA \times 3.5V = 0.44W $$

Consequently, power dissipated in the regulator has fallen to:

$$ P_{U1} = 125mA \times 3.5V = 0.44W $$

That's a much more reasonable power for the regulator to handle without any heat-sinking. The resistor will also get warm, of course, and you'll need to use a resistor rated at ½W or 1W, but again 0.44W is nothing to worry about.

The caveat is that if your load draws *more* than 125mA, the voltage across R1 will increase, possibly causing the regulator's input to fall below it's minimum acceptable value, which is about 7.5V for the 7805.